# How to group by month using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datediff

I have a table which has this schema

```
ItemID    UserID    Year    IsPaid    PaymentDate  Amount
1         1         2009    0         2009-11-01  300
2         1         2009    0         2009-12-01  342
3         1         2010    0         2010-01-01  243
4         1         2010    0         2010-02-01  2543
5         1         2010    0         2010-03-01  475
```

I'm trying to get a query working which shows the totals for each month. So far I've tried DateDiff and nested selects, but neither gives me what I want. This is the closest I have I think:

```
DECLARE @start [datetime] = 2010/4/1;
SELECT ItemID, IsPaid,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 And DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 0 AND UserID = 100) AS "Apr",
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =1 AND UserID = 100) AS "May",
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =2 AND UserID = 100) AS "Jun", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =3 AND UserID = 100) AS "Jul", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =4  AND UserID = 100) AS "Aug", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =5  AND UserID = 100) AS "Sep", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =6  AND UserID = 100) AS "Oct", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =7 AND UserID = 100) AS "Nov", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =8 AND UserID = 100) AS "Dec", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =9 AND UserID = 100) AS "Jan", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =10 AND UserID = 100) AS "Feb", 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 AND DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) =11 AND UserID = 100) AS "Mar" 
FROM LIVE L INNER JOIN Payments I ON I.LiveID = L.RECORD_KEY 
WHERE UserID = 16178
```

But I just get nulls when I should be getting values. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to pivot the table to show columns by year/month with a sum of payments by userid under it?

Comment: Why does your UserID = 16178 in the where clause different than UserID = 100 in your subquery where clause? Also the last 3 subqueries for Jan, Feb and Mar, are their month differences from Apr really 9, 10, and 11 respectively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by month from Date field using sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565788/how-to-group-by-month-from-date-field-using-sql)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), PaymentDate, 120) [Month], SUM(Amount) [TotalAmount]
FROM Payments
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), PaymentDate, 120)
ORDER BY [Month]
```

You could also try:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, PaymentDate) Year, DATEPART(Month, PaymentDate) Month, SUM(Amount) [TotalAmount]
FROM Payments
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, PaymentDate), DATEPART(Month, PaymentDate)
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

Comment: Just use commas in MySql like this `group by year(date),month(date)`

Answer (score 28):

Restrict the dimension of the NVARCHAR to 7, supplied to CONVERT to show only "YYYY-MM"

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7),PaymentDate,120) [Month], SUM(Amount) [TotalAmount]
FROM Payments
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7),PaymentDate,120)
ORDER BY [Month]
```

Answer (score 14):

I prefer combining `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` functions like this:

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Created),0)
```

Together, these two functions zero-out the date component *smaller* than the specified *datepart* (i.e. `MONTH` in this example).

You can change the [datepart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) bit to `YEAR`, `WEEK`, `DAY`, etc... which is super handy.

Your original SQL query would then look something like this (I can't test it as I don't have your data set, but it should put you on the right track).

```
DECLARE @start [datetime] = '2010-04-01';

SELECT
    ItemID,
    UserID,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Created),0) [Month],
    IsPaid,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM LIVE L
INNER JOIN Payments I ON I.LiveID = L.RECORD_KEY
WHERE UserID = 16178
AND PaymentDate > @start
```

One more thing: the `Month` column is typed as a `DateTime` which is also a nice advantage if you need to further process that data or map it .NET object for example.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this frequently, I would probably add a computed column `PaymentMonth` to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Payments ADD PaymentMonth AS MONTH(PaymentDate) PERSISTED
```

It's persisted and stored in the table - so there's really no performance overhead querying it. It's a 4 byte INT value - so the space overhead is minimal, too.

Once you have that, you could simplify your query to be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT ItemID, IsPaid,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 And PaymentMonth = 1 AND UserID = 100) AS 'Jan',
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Payments WHERE Year = 2010 And PaymentMonth = 2 AND UserID = 100) AS 'Feb',
.... and so on .....
FROM LIVE L 
INNER JOIN Payments I ON I.LiveID = L.RECORD_KEY 
WHERE UserID = 16178
```

Comment: Is there a performance overhead?  Even on a low spec box, SQL Server can do several million `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7),PaymentDate,120)` per second.  I'm not sure using a computed column would provide any benefit (unless you were to index it perhaps)

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @start [datetime] = 2010/4/1;
```

Should be...

```
DECLARE @start [datetime] = '2010-04-01';
```

The one you have is dividing 2010 by 4, then by 1, then converting to a date.  Which is the 57.5th day from 1900-01-01.

Try `SELECT @start` after your initialisation to check if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, that doesn't involve adding columns to the result, is to simply zero-out the `day` component of the date, so `2016-07-13` and `2016-07-16` would both be `2016-07-01` - thus making them equal by month.

If you have a `date` (not a `datetime`) value, then you can zero it directly:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD( day, 1 - DATEPART( day, [Date] ), [Date] ),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    [Table]
GROUP BY
    DATEADD( day, 1 - DATEPART( day, [Date] ), [Date] )
```

If you have `datetime` values, you'll need to use `CONVERT` to remove the time-of-day portion:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD( day, 1 - DATEPART( day, [Date] ),  CONVERT( date, [Date] ) ),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    [Table]
GROUP BY
    DATEADD( day, 1 - DATEPART( day, [Date] ),  CONVERT( date, [Date] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Now your query is explicitly looking at only payments for year = 2010, however, I think you meant to have your Jan/Feb/Mar actually represent 2009.  If so, you'll need to adjust this a bit for that case.  Don't keep requerying the sum values for every column, just the condition of the date difference in months.  Put the rest in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 0 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Apr",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 1 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "May",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 2 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "June",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 3 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "July",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 4 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Aug",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 5 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Sep",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 6 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Oct",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 7 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Nov",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 8 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Dec",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 9 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Jan",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 10 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Feb",
      SUM( case when DateDiff(m, PaymentDate, @start) = 11 
           then Amount else 0 end ) AS "Mar"
   FROM 
      Payments I
         JOIN Live L
            on I.LiveID = L.Record_Key
   WHERE 
          Year = 2010 
      AND UserID = 100
```