# How to group by month from Date field using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I group only by month from a date field (and not group by day)?

Here is what my date field looks like:

```
2012-05-01
```

Here is my current SQL:

```
select  Closing_Date, Category,  COUNT(Status)TotalCount from  MyTable
where Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' and Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
and Defect_Status1 is not null
group by  Closing_Date, Category
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I would use this:

```
SELECT  Closing_Date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Closing_Date), 0), 
        Category,  
        COUNT(Status) TotalCount 
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' 
AND     Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND     Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Closing_Date), 0), Category;
```

This will group by the first of every month, so

```
`DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '20130128'), 0)`
```

will give `'20130101'`. I generally prefer this method as it keeps dates as dates.

Alternatively you could use something like this:

```
SELECT  Closing_Year = DATEPART(YEAR, Closing_Date),
        Closing_Month = DATEPART(MONTH, Closing_Date),
        Category,  
        COUNT(Status) TotalCount 
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' 
AND     Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND     Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, Closing_Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Closing_Date), Category;
```

It really depends what your desired output is. (Closing Year is not necessary in your example, but if the date range crosses a year boundary it may be).

Comment: GarethD, thanks man both method worked fine.  Is there a way i can group both the year and the month together in one field?  Meaning to show like this format: Dec-12 (Dec is the month and 12 is the year).  thanks

Comment: The first method will do this, you just need to format the column. I'd advise doing this outside of SQL, but if it has to be done as such you can use something like `SELECT STUFF(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 6), 4, 6), 4, 1, '-');`

Comment: @GarethD Could you explain how did you just use datediff between 0 and date. 0 is not a date.

Comment: and also what does Closing_Date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Closing_Date), 0) do why not just DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Closing_Date), 0)

Comment: @irfandar 0 is not a date, but SQL-Server implicitly converts it to 1st January 1900. For your second question `Closing_Date =` is just the column alias, it is the same as having `AS Closing_Date` after the expression. It is entirely subjective but I personally find the `alias =` notation much easier to read than `AS Alias`. For more on why I prefer it [read this article](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: Thanks for a really nice solution.

Answer (score 54):

Use the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to extract the month from the date.

So you would do something like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, Closing_Date) AS Closing_Month, COUNT(Status) AS TotalCount
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEPART(month, Closing_Date)
```

Comment: For Mysql you can use MONTH() or MONTHNAME() instead of DATEPART

Comment: If you run this query often, consider to build an appropriate index.

Comment: Plus 1 for simple reply.

Comment: This would consider months from different years the same -- which is typically NOT was is expected.

Comment: This puts a "1" for january etc.. It doesn't tell you the month name

Comment: Adding a date range will prevent data from different years.

Answer (score 26):

I used the [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function to accomplish this:

```sql
select
   FORMAT(Closing_Date, 'yyyy_MM') AS Closing_Month
   , count(*) cc 
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
    AND Closing_Date >= '2011-12-01'
    AND Closing_Date < '2016-07-01' 
GROUP BY
    FORMAT(Closing_Date, 'yyyy_MM')
ORDER BY
    Closing_Month
```

Comment: this will not work because you cannot alias in the ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 19):

By Adding `MONTH(date_column)` in `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT Closing_Date, Category,  COUNT(Status)TotalCount
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' AND Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND    Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(Closing_Date), Category
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2012 version above,

```
SELECT  format(Closing_Date,'yyyy-MM') as ClosingMonth,
        Category,  
        COUNT(Status) TotalCount 
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' 
AND     Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND     Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY format(Closing_Date,'yyyy-MM'), Category;
```

Answer (score 2):

DATEPART function doesn't work on MySQL 5.6, instead use MONTH('2018-01-01')

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select min(closing_date), date_part('month',closing_date) || '-' || date_part('year',closing_date) AS month,
Category, COUNT(Status)TotalCount 
FROM MyTable
where Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' AND Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND Defect_Status1 is not null
GROUP BY month, Category,
ORDER BY 1
```

This way you are grouping by a concatenated date format, joined by a -

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  to_char(Closing_Date,'MM'), 
        Category,  
        COUNT(Status) TotalCount 
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' 
AND     Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND     Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using recent MSSQL versions and chancing upon this question ... SQL Server 2022 introduces a new function, which serves exactly this purpose: `DATE_BUCKET`. It is very flexible, allowing us to easily group the data by any interval, from years to milliseconds.

Using this, OP's query would become:

```
SELECT  Closing_Date = DATE_BUCKET(MONTH, 1, Closing_Date), 
        Category,
        COUNT(Status) TotalCount
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01'
AND     Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND     Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATE_BUCKET(MONTH, 1, Closing_Date), Category;
```

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using Year(), Month() Day() and datepart().

In you example this would be:

```
select  Closing_Date, Category,  COUNT(Status)TotalCount from  MyTable
where Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' and Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31' 
and Defect_Status1 is not null 
group by Year(Closing_Date), Month(Closing_Date), Category
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL

Comment: Well this is valid but brings unpredictable results as you don't group by the fields that you select. You can have any value in closing date as long as the date and the year are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try the Following Code

```
SELECT  Closing_Date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Closing_Date), 0), 
        Category,  
        COUNT(Status) TotalCount 
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Closing_Date >= '2012-02-01' 
AND     Closing_Date <= '2012-12-31'
AND     Defect_Status1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Closing_Date), 0), Category;
```