# Transposing data ( calculating monthly sales data) in sql

Tags: sql, mysqli

My data has total 100 rows

```
Day         Item    Price Unit
01/01/17    jeans     15   4
01/02/17    shirt     10   3
01/01/17    skirt     20   7
01/04/17    skirt     25   1
02/01/17    jeans     5   4
02/02/17    shirt    15   3
02/01/17    skirt     24   7
03/04/17    skirt     25   5
```

I want ro represent my data as monthly sale by item in january and february

data should represent as

```
month jeans skirt shirt total
Jan
Feb
```

I am getting error in my code

```
SELECT MONTH,
MAX(CASE WHEN ITEM = 'JEANS' THEN GRANDTOTAL END) GRANDTOTAL,
MAX(CASE WHEN ITEM = 'SHIRT' THEN GRANDTOTAL END) AS GRANDTOTAL,
MAX(CASE WHEN ITEM = 'SKIRT' THEN GRANDTOTAL END) AS GRANDTOTAL, 
FROM SALES 
GROUP BY MONTH ;
```

I tried all methods but getting error, please help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by month from Date field using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565788/how-to-group-by-month-from-date-field-using-sql)

Comment: I am getting error in my code  SELECT MONTH,
MAX( CASE WHEN ITEM = 'JEANS' THEN GRANDTOTAL END) GRANDTOTAL,
MAX( CASE WHEN ITEM = 'SHIRT' THEN GRANDTOTAL END) AS GRANDTOTAL,
MAX( CASE WHEN ITEM = 'SKIRT' THEN GRANDTOTAL END) AS GRANDTOTAL,

FROM SALES
GROUP BY MONTH ;

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You ought to accept @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ's contribution if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sales per item is defined as the sum of price x unit while total sales is the sum of sales for all items.

see demo: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a9e8f/1

```
SELECT date_format(day, '%b') as `month`,
sum(case when item='jeans' then price*unit else 0 end) as jeans,
sum(case when item='shirt' then price*unit else 0 end) as shirts,
sum(case when item='skirt' then price*unit else 0 end) as skirts,
sum(price*unit) as total
FROM myTbl
where month(day) <= 2
GROUP BY date_format(day, '%b')
ORDER BY month(day);

result:
month   jeans   shirts  skirts  total
Jan       60      30         165         255
Feb   20        45       168         233
```

Comment: I am getting error, from keyword not found where expected,               
  also need data only for jan and feb.  Here price represents sales

Comment: I updated my answer. Also it has no syntax error since it has a sample dta and result in sqlfiddle.com:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a9e8f/1.  Pls make sure you copy and paste properly

Comment: Hey, Thanks for code,  I got it, but as the price itself is sales value and I am thinking that it should be sum(price) as aggregate. Can you tell me on that.

Comment: if you define sales as price value then you are correct and sum(price) is correct.  if you like my amswer pls accept it by clicking on check button

Comment: Hey, I am getting invalid character error, can it be because of hypens on month in first line of command, code works fine on fiddle, but when i am running it in apex.oracle, I get invalid character error.. please guide me on that

Comment: it is called caret. you can remove it and use "month" instead. If still not working try, reporting_month. The word Month is a reserved word so you need to put an escape characters Or name it differently.