# Group by month taking into account on timezone (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've seen the following question about grouping by month:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Closing_Date), 0)
```

[How to group by month from Date field using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565788/how-to-group-by-month-from-date-field-using-sql)

This works - but I want to run this against a specific timezone, taking DST into account.

To be specific, the Netherlands timezone: Central European Standard Time (GMT+1).

This will be GMT+2 sometimes with DST.

In my case I have an `Orders` table with an `OrderDatetime` which is a `DateTimeOffset(7)`. all values are UTC (+00:00).

```sql
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Orders].[OrderDateTime]), 0) AS [Month],
    ...
FROM 
    [Orders]
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Orders].[OrderDateTime]), 0)
```

What would such query look like when taking into account a specific timezone?

**Bonus**: I'd preferably make this configurable, so the timezone would be a parameter - what would such query look like?

Comment: *" all values are UTC (+00:00) - but contain data from multiple timezones."* That statement conflicts with itself. If all the values are UTC+0 then they aren't from different timezones...

Comment: @Larnu I meant that data is inserted from different timezones, then converted to UTC and saved to the database - i've removed that part i don't think its relevant ayways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `datetimeoffset` columns you could use the `AT TIME ZONE` keywords when SELECT'ing the rows

[Edit]: Added DECLARE'ed variable to make TZ configurable

```
drop table if exists #YourTable;
go
CREATE TABLE #YourTable(
  YourColumn datetimeoffset(7));

insert #YourTable (YourColumn) VALUES
('2022-01-24T13:00:00+00:00'),
('2022-01-24T14:00:00+00:00'),
('2022-01-24T12:00:00+00:00');

declare @MyTZ       sysname=N'Central European Standard Time';

select *, YourColumn at time zone @MyTZ conv_tz
from #YourTable;
```

```
YourColumn                          conv_tz
2022-01-24 13:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2022-01-24 14:00:00.0000000 +01:00
2022-01-24 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2022-01-24 15:00:00.0000000 +01:00
2022-01-24 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2022-01-24 13:00:00.0000000 +01:00
```

To use in your formula would be like this:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, YourColumn at time zone @MyTZ), 0) YourColTZ
```

Comment: Yes this seems to be what i'm looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SWITCHOFFSET`

```
CREATE TABLE test   
(  
   OrderDateTime datetimeoffset 
,  tz varchar (8)
);  

INSERT INTO test   
VALUES ('2022-01-31 17:00:00 -5:00', '+08:00');  
 
SELECT 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [OrderDateTime]), 0) AS [Month1]
  , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SWITCHOFFSET (OrderDateTime, tz)), 0) AS [Month2]
  
FROM test;
```

Returns

```
Month1  Month2
2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work, but does not seem to take DST into account. quite useful however if i want to ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is already a `datetimeoffset` then SQL Server already takes timezones into account, so I suspect the problem you think exists, doesn't.

Take the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourColumn datetimeoffset(7));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (YourColumn)
VALUES('2022-01-24T13:00:00+00:00'),
      ('2022-01-24T14:00:00+00:00'),
      ('2022-01-24T12:00:00+00:00');
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE YourColumn = CONVERT(datetimeoffset(7),'2022-01-24T14:00:00+01:00');
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

This returns the row with the value `2022-01-24T13:00:00.0000000 +00:00` because `2022-01-24T13:00:00.0000000 +00:00` and `2022-01-24T14:00:00+01:00` are the same time.