# Adding all the amounts per month using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my data

```
date           amount
2017-07-10     15.00
2017-07-10     15.00
2017-07-28     25.00
2017-08-01     100.00
2017-08-12     15.00
2017-08-29     200.00
2017-09-18     105.00
2017-09-21     200.00
2017-09-23     25.00
2017-10-12     15.00
2017-10-14     500.00
2017-11-01     200.00
2017-11-02     200.00
```

I want to add it by month so what we will get that in June i got a total of 55, August i will get 315, September 330, October 515, November 400 and the past dates with no amount will be 0 how will i do that?

Here is my temporary table codes:

```
create table #TempTable
    (month varchar(50),
    amount decimal(18,2))


insert into #TempTable (month)
SELECT TOP 12
DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1,0))
FROM sys.columns

create table #Data
    (date date,
    amount decimal(18,2))
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-07-10',15.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-07-10',15.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-07-28',25.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-08-01',100.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-08-12',15.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-08-29',200.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-09-18',105.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-09-21',200.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-09-23',25.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-10-12',15.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-10-14',500.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-11-01',200.00)
  insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-11-02',200.00)

  select * from #Data
  select * from #TempTable
drop table #TempTable
drop table #Data
```

PS. Just update the #TempTable and put the total on it thank you :)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `MONTH()`.

Comment: Plus for one test data,also please include expected result as text and any query attempt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Group By Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345282/sql-server-group-by-month)

Comment: Remember if you group by month, you probably need to group by year if you date range is longer than 12 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
SELECT Res1.[Month]
         ,ISNULL(Res2.Amount,0)
  FROM #TempTable Res1
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  select DATENAME(MONTH,Res1.date) AS [Month]
         ,SUM(amount) AS Amount 
  from #Data Res1
  GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,Res1.date) 
  )Res2 ON Res2.[Month] = Res1.[Month]
```

Comment: Please learn how to format your code. Also, this answer has the same issue as the other one.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT a.Month,SUM(ISNULL(b.Amount,0)) 
  FROM  #TempTable a
  LEFT JOIN #Data b
  ON a.Month = DATENAME(MONTH,date)
  GROUP BY a.Month
```

for update

```
   UPDATE a
  SET Amount = ISNULL(GroupSuma,0)
  FROM  #TempTable a
  LEFT JOIN
  (
      select DATENAME(MONTH,date) as month, SUM(b.Amount) as GroupSuma
      FROM #Data b
      GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,date)
  ) as c
  ON a.Month = c.Month
```

Comment: This will fail if the date range is longer than 1 year.

Comment: You got it man, but the thing is the Month, is not in order, it rather starts in April instead of January

Comment: @GGw Without (plus one) please.

Comment: @GGw If it doesn't answer your question, how can it be the correct query?

Answer (score 1):

update temptable from data table

```
update #TempTable
set amount = d.amount from ( select  datename(month, date) date
                                     , SUM(amount) amount from #Data
                                     group by datename(month, date)
                                     ) d inner join #TempTable t on t.month = d.date

                                     select * from #TempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your requirements is:

> past dates with no amount will be 0

Your dataset didn't include this so I've added two additional rows in the example code below. I also added a different year to illustrate what happens with different years.  I UNION ALL the values from #data with a CTE that select years, every month# of year, and 0.  When SUM'ed, most of the 0 entries are eliminated, but months in the year without values in #Data remain with amount = 0. This result is subqueried to eliminate the 0 rows out of range of the min and max dates in #data.

```
create table #Data (date date, amount decimal(18,2))
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-07-10',15.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-07-10',15.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-07-28',25.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-08-01',100.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-08-12',15.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-08-29',200.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-09-18',105.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-09-21',200.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-09-23',25.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-10-12',15.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-10-14',500.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-11-01',200.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-11-02',200.00)

--additional test values
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2017-05-04',5.00)
insert into #Data(date,amount) values('2018-02-22',1.00)

DECLARE @minYear int =  (SELECT YEAR(MIN(date)) FROM #data)
       ,@minMonth int =  (SELECT MONTH(MIN(date)) FROM #data)
       ,@maxYear int =  (SELECT MAX(YEAR(date)) FROM #data)
       ,@maxMonth int =  (SELECT MONTH(MAX(date)) FROM #data);

WITH cteYear AS 
(
  SELECT @minYear AS num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT num + 1 FROM cteYear WHERE num + 1 <= @maxYear
)

SELECT dT.dateyear
      ,DateName( month , DateAdd( month , dT.datemonth, -1 ) ) AS [month]
      ,SUM(dT.amount) AS [Sum Amount]
  FROM (
         SELECT YEAR(date) AS [dateyear], MONTH(date) AS [datemonth], amount -- AS [SumAmount]     
           FROM #Data D       

         UNION ALL

         SELECT num, monthlist.month, 0 
           FROM cteYear CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS [month] UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL 
                                    SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
                                    SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
                                   ) AS monthlist
       ) AS dT
WHERE (@minYear <> @maxYear AND dateyear = @minYear AND datemonth >= @minMonth)
      OR
      (@minYear <> @maxYear AND dateyear = @maxYear AND datemonth <= @maxMonth)
      OR
      (@minYear <> @maxYear AND dateyear <> @minYear AND dateyear <> @maxYear)
      OR
      (@minYear = @maxYear AND datemonth >= @minMonth AND datemonth <= @maxMonth)


GROUP BY dateyear, datemonth
ORDER BY dateyear, datemonth
```

Gives output:

```
dateyear    month      Sum Amount
2017        May        5.00
2017        June       0.00
2017        July       55.00
2017        August     315.00
2017        September  330.00
2017        October    515.00
2017        November   400.00
2017        December   0.00
2018        January    0.00
2018        February   1.00
```